# Mongodb group and sort

Tags: mongodb

How can I translate the following `Sql` query for `Mongo`?:

```sql
select a,b,sum(c) csum from coll where active=1 group by a,b order by a
```

Is there any way to execute a group and sort query with Mongo?

Answer (score 29):

Inspired by this [example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/) on mongo's website.

GENERATE DUMMY DATA:

```
> db.stack.insert({a:1,b:1,c:1,active:1})
> db.stack.insert({a:1,b:1,c:2,active:0})
> db.stack.insert({a:1,b:2,c:3,active:1})
> db.stack.insert({a:1,b:2,c:2,active:0})
> db.stack.insert({a:2,b:1,c:3,active:1})
> db.stack.insert({a:2,b:1,c:10,active:1})
> db.stack.insert({a:2,b:2,c:10,active:0})
> db.stack.insert({a:2,b:2,c:5,active:1})
```

MONGO QUERY:

```
> db.stack.aggregate(
... {$match:{active:1}},
... {$group:{_id:{a:"$a", b:"$b"}, csum:{$sum:"$c"}}},
... {$sort:{"_id.a":1}})
```

RESULT:

```
{"result" : [
    {"_id" : {"a" : 1,"b" : 2},"csum" : 3},
    {"_id" : {"a" : 1,"b" : 1},"csum" : 1},
    {"_id" : {"a" : 2,"b" : 2},"csum" : 5},
    {"_id" : {"a" : 2,"b" : 1},"csum" : 13}
],"ok" : 1}
```

(NOTE: I reformatted the shell result a bit so it is more readable)

Answer (score 19):

Using the aggregate framework, you can do the following:

```js
db.coll.aggregate({ 
    $group: { 
        _id: "$a", 
        countA: { $sum: 1}, 
        sumC:{ $sum: "$c"}, 
    },
    $sort:{a:1}
});
```

However, if you have too much data you may get the following error message:

```
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
    "code" : 16389,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

See more about SQL to Mongo translation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: Marius, Disregard my edit, I must have had something else wrong, it works as you wrote it! Sorry!

Comment: This doesnt work anymore: "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."

Comment: @user3690202 That's because aggregate now expects an array of objects instead of a single object with multiple fields.

Answer (score 6):

The mongodb aggregation API seems to have changed. Now you would do

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
     $group: { 
        _id: "$a", 
        countA: { $sum: 1}, 
        sumC:{ $sum: "$c"}, 
     }
  },
  {
    $sort:{a:1}
  }
])
```

Note the Array syntax for the argument to aggregate(). You'd also add things link $match, $limit etc. as elements of this array.

Answer (score 4):

I built up a histogram and what I did with version 2.2.2 was:

```
answer = db.coll.group(...)
db.histo.insert(answer)
db.histo.find().sort({ field: 1 })
```

At this point, if you don't need it, just `db.histo.drop()`.

You can also avoid the variable and do:

```
db.histo.insert(db.coll.group(...))
db.histo.ensureIndex({ field: 1 })
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the $group and $sort in aggregate in the order **$group** > **$sort** .
Using the sort before group won't work.
Consider the example below:

```
let data = await ABCModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: { city: { $nin: ['', null] }},
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $toLower: '$city' }
        },
      },
      { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.coll.group(
       {key: { a:true, b:true },
        cond: { active:1 },
        reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.csum += obj.c; },
        initial: { csum: 0 }
        });
```

You can execute it in MongoDB

Comment: There is only group, where is sort/order by?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to previous answers, if you want to sort on the sum (the result of the aggregate) instead of on the actual column, you can do this:

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {_id: "$your_document_name", count: {$sum: 1}}
    }, 
    {
        $sort: {"count":-1}
    }
])
```

This would be the equivalent of the following standard-SQL-ish syntax:

```
select col_a, count(col_a) as b
from table
group by col_a
order by b desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add the following query, as an example, it may be useful in case of two groupings.

Query:

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
    {$match:{
        tipo: {$regex:"[A-Z]+"}
        }
    },
    {$group:
        { 
            _id:{
                codigo:"1",
                fechaAlta:{$substr:["$fechaAlta",0,10]},
            },
            total:{$sum:1}
        }
    },
    {$sort:
        {"_id":1}
    },
    {$group:
        {
            _id:"$_id.codigo",
            fechasAltas:
            {
                $push:
                {
                    fechaAlta:"$_id.fechaAlta",
                    total:"$total"
                }
            },
            totalGeneral:{$sum:"$total"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Response:

```
{
"_id" : "1",
"fechasAltas" : [ 
    {
        "fechaAlta" : "1940-01-01",
        "total" : 13.0
    }, 
    {
        "fechaAlta" : "2007-05-14",
        "total" : 115.0
    }, 
    {
        "fechaAlta" : "2008-09-30",
        "total" : 58.0
    }, 

    .
    .
    .
],
"totalGeneral" : 50620.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until the [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) is release in MongoDB 2.1, the call for group as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298315/179529), is rather slow, since it is using the JavaScript part of the DB.

You can use a faster approach for *counting* groups:

```
var res = [];
for( var cur_a = db.coll.distinct('a'); cur_a.hasNext(); ) {
  var a = cur_a.next();
  for( var cur_b = db.coll.distinct('b'); cur_b.hasNext(); ) {
    var b = cur_b.next();
    res.push({ 'a': a, 'b' : b 'count': db.coll.count({'a':a,'b':b})}
  }
}
```

It will be faster if you have indexes on *a* and *b*

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({'a':1,'b':1})
```