# how can sort group by result in PHP MongoDB

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

in php i have created a cursor which hold group by result from MongoDB with following command.

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->Forensic;
$c= $db->mobile_data;

// JavaScript function to perform
$reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }";

//group by source (number of messages);
$d = $c->group( ["Source" => 1], ["count" => 0], $reduce);
```

how can I sort my result based on "Source" key.

Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

[I would refer you to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547441/mongodb-group-and-sort) and see if that helps. There is also a link to the MongoDB documentation that might help you as well. [There is also a decent explanation here also](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-aggregate-and-group-example/).

I'm just dabbling in group and sort in MongoDB myself.

One example I found was;

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
     $group: {
        _id: "$cust_id",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
     }
   },
   { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } }
])
```

[and there is also a similar thread here as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451322/mongodb-aggregation-sort)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I know how to sort result from mongodb platform, but currently I am passing my command from php. how to write code  in php group by sort would be much appreciate

Comment: In PHP or on SQL?

Comment: PHP commad like      $d = $c->group( ["Source" => 1], ["count" => 0], $reduce, Sort("Source"));

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative solution

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->Forensic;
$c= $db->mobile_data;

// JavaScript function to perform
$reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }";

//group by source (number of messages);
$d = $c->group( ["Source" => 1], ["count" => 0], $reduce);

//sort record
sort($d['retval']);
```

which will sort by Source field